# How to transform data from the Google Analytics Reports module into charts?

Tags: views, google-analytics, charts

I'm using [Google Analytics Reports](https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) to bring in Google Analytics data into [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), this works fine, but I'd like to display this data as a chart.

I've tried with two different charts modules: [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) and [Google Chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools). Both require you to use `Aggregation` in views to group the data, but this isn't something the [Google Analytics Reports](https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) module supports.

Can anyone recommend a way around this or a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the API sub-module within the Google Analytics Reports module and use

[DataViz module](https://drupal.org/project/views_dataviz) for the visual representation.

You could use http://blog.amazeelabs.com/en/comment/257249 for reference.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Google Analytics Reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) issue about "[Use Aggregation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2006088)", the 7.x-3.x version (for which only a beta2 is available at this moment) should support this now.

That's also what's written in comment #1 of it, ie:

> See chart examples in the latest 7.x-3.x version.

What isn't obvious to discover, is that these examples have a weak module dependency of the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module:

- [If the Charts module exists](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/google_analytics_reports/tree/google_analytics_reports.views_default.inc#n397), then (and only then ...) the sample view is available.
- Though the [.info file](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/google_analytics_reports/tree/google_analytics_reports.info) of the [Google Analytics Reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) module does not mention [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) as a dependency.

So if the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module isn't enabled yet, these example charts will show up as soon as you (download and) enable it.

Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module.